# how do I get a post id in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a toggle like button for posts, but i cant get a post id to do it.

[image]

```
export function toggleLike(postId) {
  const postLikesRef = ref(database, `posts/${postId}/likes`);

  runTransaction(postLikesRef, (currentLikes) => {
    if (currentLikes) {
      return currentLikes - 1; 
    } else {
      return 1; 
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the key of the post you want to run a transaction on, then all you can do is run a transaction on all posts.

Since that is unlikely what you want, you'll need to:

1. Get the key of each post when you render each post. You can get it from `snapshot.key` where you already use `snapshot.val()`.
2. Render the key somewhere into the UI of that specific post.
3. Then pass that key to your `toggleLike` when the user clicks the toggle in the UI.